# start unicorn on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raspberry-pi, unicorn, rbenv

I'm using Rails 4 + Nginx + Unicorn and I want that when my raspberry pi is rebooted it should run Rails application on startup.

Issue: The Nginx is running but unicorn is **not running**.

I've put in `/etc/rc.local` file the following command

```
cd /opt/www/RAILSAPP/current && bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

but its not up when I'm rebooting. when I'm accessing the pi via ssh and run the command its working.

#### How can I start unicorn on startup in order to serve the rails app?

Comment: does that command works if you execute it manually in the console and outside the current path?